# goroutine didn't respect `ctx.done()` or quit properly

Tags: go

I am trying to achieve quit gracefully when user press `Ctrl-C`. I am trying the code in [Make Ctrl+C cancel the context.Context](https://medium.com/@matryer/make-ctrl-c-cancel-the-context-context-bd006a8ad6ff). 
    package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()

    // trap Ctrl+C and call cancel on the context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    defer func() {
        signal.Stop(c)
        cancel()
        fmt.Println("Cleaned up")
    }()
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-c:
            fmt.Println("Got interrupt signal")
            cancel()
        case <-ctx.Done():
        }
        fmt.Println("Stopped monitoring")
    }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("notified to quit")
    case <-time.NewTimer(time.Second * 2).C:
        fmt.Println("done something")
    }
}
```

It works well as expected when user press `Ctrl-c`, it console out the following:

```
Got interrupt signal
Stopped monitoring
notified to quit
Cleaned up
```

However, if it quit normally, It doesn't work as expected as below:

```
done something
Cleaned up
```

I mean it should print out `Stopped monitoring`, but not. In `defer cleanup` function, it called `cancel()` which should trigger the `select in monitoring goroutine` to quit, but not.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: You don't wait for a cancel. You just exit main, hit the defer, and vaporize the program before the goroutine runs.

Comment: Very true, it didn't wait for that goroutine to quit. I modified the code and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Zan Lynx,  I worked out the below solution.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    terminated := monitor(ctx, cancel)
    defer func() {
        cancel()
        fmt.Println("Cleaned up")
        <-terminated // wait for the monior goroutine quit
    }()
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("notified to quit")
    case <-time.NewTimer(time.Second * 1).C:
        fmt.Println("done something")
    }
}

func monitor(ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc) <-chan interface{} {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt)
    terminated := make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        defer close(terminated)
        defer fmt.Println("Stopped monitoring1")
        defer signal.Stop(c)
        select {
        case <-c:
            fmt.Println("Got interrupt singnal")
            cancel()
        case <-ctx.Done():
        }
    }()
    return terminated
}
```